# Как сделать корректное отображение отступа у textView внутри RecyclerView?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Есть `RecyclerView`, вот как выглядит один элемент(item.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <com.company.testapp10.ProportionalImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Изображение большое и сжимается в ширине до 110dp соблюдая пропорции, вот код ProportionalImageView:

```
public class ProportionalImageView extends ImageView {
    public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
            int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = (w * d.getIntrinsicHeight()) / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            setMeasuredDimension(w, h);

            ViewParent viewParent = getParent();
            if(viewParent instanceof RelativeLayout) {
                RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) viewParent;
                parentLayout.getLayoutParams().height = h;
            }

        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Если item.xml использовать не в списке(первая view на рисунке) нижний отступ у `textView` отображается корректно, но если внутри списка(последующие view на рисунке) то его просто нет. После прокручивания списка отступы появляются. Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать нормальное отображение отступа у textView?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать layout_alignParentEnd

Comment: @Dimanoid не помогло

Comment: а если android:layout_margin у текствью заменить на android:padding ?
воспроизводится при любых размерах изображения? а с обычным ImageView?

Comment: @Dimanoid да, действительно android:padding работает. Как я сам не подумал его установить. Спасибо. Интересно почему margin не работает. С обычным ImageView ошибка остается.

Comment: @Dimanoid и можете написать ответ ниже, я отмечу его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `android:layout_margin` у текствью заменить на `android:padding`.

На мысль натолкнуло не очень понятное описание `android:layout_alignParentBottom`

> If true, makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of the parent. **Accommodates bottom margin.**

Честно говоря не очень понял что они имели в виду. Но раз `padding` не упомянут, стоило его попробовать. Хорошо что сработало. :)

Answer (score 1):

я бы посоветовал поместить в ваш .xml файл следующее android.support.v7.widget.CardView, примерно с такими параметрами

```
   `android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp">`
```

до этого конечно не забудьте импортировать в build.gradle > dependencies >compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'

а дальше уже поиграетесь со значениями)